# When comparing array elements of two arrays, boolean result always returns true

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I am having an issue when comparing elements in two int arrays. I am using a for loop to compare each element in the two arrays, and if the elements match, the boolean result is to return true, and if not, return false. The problem is that it is always returning true, regardless of whether they match or not.

Entire program here http://pastebin.ca/2626244

the loop:

```
    boolean result;
    int counter = 0;
    //compares answers[] to key[]
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  {
        if (answers[i] == key[i]) {
            result = true; 
            }
        if (answers[i] != key[i]) {
            result = false;
        }
        if (result = true) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter+"/"+size+" questions are correct.");
```

As a result, "counter" is always the same value as the total elements ("size"). Even if both arrays contain completely different values, the result still will not be 0/size. It always seems to be size/size.

Am I comparing the arrays incorrectly (see full program), or is there just something wrong with my loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the comparison operator `==` to compare things, not the assignment operator `=`.  But because `result` is a `boolean` already, just use the `boolean` itself.

Change

```
if (result = true) {
```

to

```
if (result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That makes the int counter work correctly now.
Why does that work? How is "if (result)" a valid statement though?

Comment: The type of the expression that the `if` statement requires is a `boolean`, and you already have a `boolean`.  You could say `if (result == true)` if you really wanted, but it's verbose and it requires an unnecessary comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
= is use to assign the value and to compare the value use `==`
```

So need to change below code :

```
if (result == true) {
    counter++;
}
```

or better solution is

```
if (result) {
    counter++;
}
```